# How to load more records on scoll end in Sencha Touch Ext.Dataview

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, sencha-touch-2

I have a sencha touch Ext.Dataview component which pulls data from a store. How to load more records in the store on scroll end of the dataview.

I am creating a HTML5 app using cordova.

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for load more records as per you want. It will only apply on **LIST** only remember.

Secnha Load More plugin [Ext.plugin.ListPagingView](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.plugin.ListPaging)

Note: In '**Store**' you need to apply config >> pageSize

> pageSize: 30, //Any Damm Number

```
{
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1,
            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                {
                    xtype:'list',
                    itemId:'asd',
                    disableSelection:true,                                                
                    id:'asd',
                    itemTpl:new Ext.XTemplate(
                        '<div class="maindiv">'+                                
                            '</div>'
                    ),
                    store:'xyz',
                    plugins: [
                        {
                            xclass: 'Ext.plugin.ListPaging',
                            noMoreRecordsText:'No More Products',
                            loadMoreText:'Load More',
                            autoPaging: true
                        }
                    ],
                    itemHeight:60
                }
            ]
        }
```